# Issues : Floating Suggestion Box in Input field on Windows 11 chrome browser

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, user-interface, material-ui, windows-10

Whenever I try to hide the recommendation box on a website that was designed with ReactJS, it just floats about as I browse over the page. I've tried clearing the cache, upgrading Chrome, and disabling extensions, but none of those things have any effect.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.